# strtok() function automatically ignores data that isn't my separation character

Tags: c, csv, strtok

I have a text file I am trying to use strtok to separate the data.  The text file looks like this.

```
SET,SDI,1,Test1
SET,SDI,2,Test 2
SET,SDI,3,Test Test 3
SET,SDI,4, Test 4
SET,SDI,5,Test  5
```

My strtok code works up until the point where spaces are introduced into the 4th value (“Test x”). Even though I specifically defined my separation character to be a comma (“,”).
Here is the output.

```
printf("%s, %s, %s, %s\n", values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3]);
SET, SDI, 1, Test1
SET, SDI, 2, Test
SET, SDI, 3, Test
SET, SDI, 4, Test
SET, SDI, 5, Test
```

Is there a way I can get strtok to recognize the 4th value as one value instead of losing the data after the whitespace?

Here is my strtok code:

```
void openfile(char *file_name){
    FILE *file;
    char line[100];
    char sep_char[] = ",";
    char* token;

    char var[20];
    char values[10][20];
    int i;


    file = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (file != NULL) {
        while (fgets(line, 100, file) != NULL) {
            i = 0;
            token = strtok(line, sep_char);
            while (token != NULL) {
                sscanf (token, "%s", &var);
                strcpy(values[i++], var);
                token = strtok(NULL, sep_char);
            }
            printf("%s, %s, %s, %s\n", values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3]);

        }
        fclose(file);
    }
    else {
        printf("Error");
    }
}
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your `sscanf` statement: it scans the token up to the first space. Just leave that line out and do

```
strcpy(values[i++], token);
```

I think that would do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with using scanf. It stops when it hits a white space character. Read the whole line using fgets, then use strtok on it. Here's the [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fgets/) for fgets.

**Edit:** I didn't look closely enough at your implementation. You are using fgets to read the line. I agree with Floris. You don't need the scanf in there. You already have a reference to the token, simply just copy it to your value array.